# Records are fetching directly from database and not from cache file

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching

I am doing a project with spring,hibernate and dojo.Initially,fetching records from database using spring-hibernate took more time.so after googling I found "second level Caching will help in fetching data faster as I saves records in some file " .So,I started implementing that.

But I whenever I execute the query it is directly hitting database and is not taking any records from cache file.

Please help me ...

enchache.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ehcache>
<defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="10000" eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="120" timeToLiveSeconds="500" />
 <cache name="com.tcs.domain.User" maxElementsInMemory="10000" eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="5" timeToLiveSeconds="500" />
</ehcache>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml :

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```

User.java :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sriram_demouser")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)  
public class User { 

............

}
```

This is my DAO implementation :

```
@Override  
@Transactional  
public List<User> getUserpagination(int page) {  

Date date= new Date();
System.out.println("Time before executing Query : "+new Timestamp(date.getTime()));

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  
  // List<User> userlist = sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class).setMaxResults(limitResultsPerPage).setFirstResult(page*limitResultsPerPage).list();  

List<User> userlist = sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User where firstName like('xyz')").setMaxResults(limitResultsPerPage).setFirstResult(((page-1)*limitResultsPerPage)).list();

  System.out.println("Time After executing Query : "+new Timestamp(date.getTime()));   


    return userlist;  

}
```

Both are printing almost same time.I wonder where this hibernate is taking more time.It is taking almost 10sec to show 500 records(Even from Cached file also)

Comment: Do you execute a query or use the hibernate methods? Also a query is always fired the results might be retrieved from a cache.

Comment: Thanks Denium for reply,I tested with both.In one method I used general query and in another method I used hibernate methods for pagination.But both are hitting database directly.How to know whether catching is done or not ?

Comment: As mentioned the query will be issued to determine which entities are needed, the entities could be resolved from the second level cache. If you want to cache a query (result) you will have to explicitly make the query cacheable.

Comment: what modifications I need to do so that my next operation will be executed from cache file and not from database.Can you please explain in detail.

Comment: Use `setCachable(true)` on the query. Post some code if you want more help.

Comment: yes..I will show my code :

    public List<User> getUserpagination(int page) {  
  
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  
      // List<User> userlist = sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class).setMaxResults(limitResultsPerPage).setFirstResult(page*limitResultsPerPage).list();  
    
    List<User> userlist = sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User where firstName like('xyz')").setMaxResults(limitResultsPerPage).setFirstResult(((page-1)*limitResultsPerPage)).list();
        
 
        return userlist;  
    }

Comment: yes..I added please check

Comment: As mention use `setCachable(true)` on the query object.

Comment: can you please help Deinum...How to use that ? @Deinum

Comment: Just like `setMaxResults` and `setFetchSize` which you are already using now.

Comment: Thnx deinum..added that and it worked.Now I am getting results from my cache file only.But it is taking nearly 10-12 secs to fetch data from file .there are only 20 records with 9 fields.Is der anything wrong with my implementation?@Deinum

Comment: HI deinum..one more issue..As you said I used setCatchable(true) but what I found is ,It is not second level caching and it is actually Query caching.Then what is the difference between Query caching and Second level caching?please find some free time to explain this....@Denium

Answer (score 0):

In your example you have in your query "where firstName like 'xzy'" but in order to hit the query cache, the query executed has to be identical, with exactly the same parameters.

If you execute "where firstName like 'John'", the first time (assuming 'hibernate.cache.use_query_cache true' and this Entity is marked as cachable) the results will go in the query cache in Second Level Cache, and subsequent times if you execute this exact same query with the same parameters, then the results will be returned from cache.

Also, if you retrieve any item by id, these will also be returned from cache (assuming they are already cached)

Comment: Hi kevin..thanks for the reply.But caching is not the problem now.I can able to get records from cached file when I execute query for the second time but it is taking too much time.

I checked by printing timestamp before and after the query but suprisingly the time remains same.So,Where it is taking too much time.Almost It is taking 10sec to fetch 500 records.
please help regarding this issue @kevin hooke

Comment: Have you tried increasing the log4j debug output from Hibernate to see what it is actually doing? Maybe it's still actually returning anything from cache? The log output should give some clues?

Comment: I never used log4j.so,I just kept print statements before and after query.Also,whenver I press next button query is not executing (I am printing query to console) but data is showing in JSP.so,It is taking more time to display in jsp.But,How to reduce that time?

Comment: Also kelvin,One more interesting thing I found.It is taking more time to go to that DAO implementation(from jsp to DAO implementation) when I press next button in both cases(from database & also from cache).Is there any way to reduce that time.

Comment: If you suspect that it's taking more time than you expect somewhere in your code, you really need to find out that that code is doing, i.e. where exactly is that time spent, and doing what? A profiler would be able to tell you this. Rather than trying to guess, get your code setup with a profiler and find out exactly what is going on. Netbeans has a built in profiler - take a look at that if you don't have any other options.

Comment: Yes Kevin Hooke,I checked wit hsimple timestamps .Found the result which is interesting.I posted the same here .please check this .

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24655247/any-reason-why-spring-hibernate-is-taking-more-time