# Any Reason why spring-hibernate is taking more time?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Currently, I am working on one project in spring and hibernate.I struck here. It is taking more time to fetch records and show those records in JSP. I kept Timestamps everywhere to see where it is taking more time:

```
Time @ HomeController[start] : 2014-07-09 18:58:52.621
**Time @ userService[start] : 2014-07-09 18:58:52.622**
**Time @ UserDao[start] : 2014-07-09 18:58:57.678**
Time before executing Query : 2014-07-09 18:58:57.678
Time After executing Query : 2014-07-09 18:58:59.272
Time @ UserDao[end] : 2014-07-09 18:58:59.272
Time @ userService[End] : 2014-07-09 18:59:00.068
Time @ HomeController[end] : 2014-07-09 18:59:00.068
Time stamp in JSP :2014-07-09 18:59:00.129
```

From above analysis, it is taking almost 5 sec to go from Service layer to DAO layer and I am giving code of Service and DAO below:

```
UserService :

     public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {  
    @Override  
    public List<User> getUserpagination(int page) {
        System.out.println("Time @ userService[start] : "+new Timestamp(new Date().getTime())); ----------- (1)
        List<User> u = userDao.getUserpagination(page);
        System.out.println("Time @ userService[End] : "+new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
        return u;
     }
  }  

UserDao :

    public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao { 
      @Override  
      @Transactional  
      public List<User> getUserpagination(int page) {  

        System.out.println("Time @ UserDao[start] : "+new Timestamp(new Date().getTime())); ------- (2)


        return userlist;  

    }
```

So, It is taking 5 sec to go from line (1) to line (2). Can anyone explain why and how to reduce that time?

I am getting database connection from properties file :

jdbc.properties :

```
database.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver 
database.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:1521:osm
database.user=osm  
database.password=xxxxxx  
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true  
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create/update
```

And below is the configuration in XML file :

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />


<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>


<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.xxx</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>

        </props>

    </property>

 </bean>

<bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Now, I used HikariCP and I am getting Timeout Error :

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/springhiber1] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is    org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate  Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException:  Cannot open connection] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: Timeout of 30000ms encountered waiting for connection.
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:192)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:91)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
```

Comment: where you are initializing `userDao` ?

Comment: Your DAO is transactional, but your service seems not to be transactional (that's a design problem already). So maybe it just takes a huge time to start the transaction because it involves getting a database connection. Check your connection pool and your database connectivity.

Comment: Depends on the scope of the DAO also, try to setup the DAO as singleton(they all run as threads,so, no worries) if it is not already a singleton

Comment: Why on earth are you constructing a timestamp, date just to print a date time. I strongly suggest simply printing the value of `System.currentTimeMillis()` instead. You are using `@Transactional` which means a transaction is started, hibernate session is created and connection is being prepared for usage. The latter is often a problem especially if you don't use a connection pool. My guess is you use the `DriverManagerDataSource` instead of a proper connection pool. Post some additional configuration.

Comment: please provide some extra information.I didn't have much knowledge on transactional.I added some code to my question so that it is easier for you to give the answer.Thanks a lot for the reply @JB Nizet

Comment: I add some additional information like database properties and XML.please check and give your inputs @M.Deinum

Comment: As mentioned you aren't using a proper JDBC ConnectionPool but the [`DriverManagerDataSource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html) this should only be used for testing not production and by no means for measuring performance. Each connection is created and destroyed and not reused. Making a connection to the database is a long and slow proces. Use a real connection pool like [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#initialization) or [C3P0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/) to name just 2.

Comment: thanks a lot .It will be helpful if you give more information regarding this connection pool like where exactly I did mistake and where I need to change.please help as I am not aware of this technology. @M.Deinum

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>
```

In your configuration you are using the [`DriverManagerDataSource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html) whilst this is a proper datasource implementation it is only that. It is not a connection pool. What happens is that each connection is created on demand and as soon it needs to be closed it will be actually closed. This is a killer for performance.

If you want to have performance use a connection pool. There are plenty of implementations out there

1. [Tomcat JDBC](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html)
2. [Commons DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/)
3. [C3P0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/)
4. [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP)

Simply replace your `dataSource` bean definition with a proper connection pool. For instance if you would want to replace it with HikariCP something like this would work.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="shutdown">
    <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" />
    <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL" />
    <property name="dataSource.user" value="${database.user}" />
    <property name="dataSource.password" value="${database.password}" />
    <property name="dataSource.url" value="${database.url}" />
</bean>
```

And of course you will have to add the dependency for the pool itself.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

For information on which properties you can set see the [HikariCP documentation](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby) and Oracle Datasource [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleDataSource.html)

Another thing is that your codebase is scattered with lines to measure performance, this really isn't the wisest thing todo nor very efficient. I suggest use a bit of AOP to apply performance measuring to your code, you can then easily remove it in production for instance. Now you have to cleanup your whole codebase.

Spring already has a [`PerformanceMonitorInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/interceptor/PerformanceMonitorInterceptor.html) which you can use and configure. If you want more elaborate measuring you can use the [`JamonPerformanceMonitorInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/interceptor/JamonPerformanceMonitorInterceptor.html).

```
<bean id="performanceInterceptor" class="org.springframework.aop.interceptor.PerformanceMonitorInterceptor"/>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="ourMethods" expression="execution(* com.your.base-package..*.*(..))"/>
    <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="ourMethods" advice-ref="performanceInterceptor"/>
</aop:config>
```

Now you have an unobtrusive way of measuring and logging performance. Keeps your code clean and tidy and you can measure what you want.

Comment: Million thanks Denium.I will try both and let u know whether they are working or not.thanks a lot @M.Denium

Comment: Getting some error while using HikariCP and I a musing spring 3.0.5 release and Hikari 1.4.Do I need to use new version of Spring jars? @M.Denium

Comment: A `DataSource` is a `DataSource` heck you could even use it with Spring 1.2. So no you shouldn't need to upgrade. I showed HikariCP as a sample use any connection pool you like, if you want to use HikariCP update your question, with your current solution and problems you have.

Comment: Hi M.Denium,Resolved the error by placing javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar .But Now I am getting Timeout error.Edited the Question again.Please check.

Comment: Please add your modified configuration.

Comment: try removing the `datasource.url` property and add `dataSource.serverName` and `dataSource.databaseName` and provide them with the correct values (name/ipadres of server and name of the database `osm` I believe).

Comment: tried with dataSource.serverName but getting the same error.And the server and database name are correct only.Earlier also I used the same @M.Denium

Comment: in general it means a problem reaching your database. Try a different connection pool.